# xcode move audio files

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I am creating iPhone application using PhoneGap. In that I have used navigator.captureAudio method to record the audio. Normally the recorded audio files stored inside the Application(tmp folder). So the application size getting increase each time while recording. I don't want to keep the recorded file inside my application.

Is there any way to move this file from application storage to outside(like music)? How to move this files in Xcode? Any suggestion on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK any files your application will create must be stored within the Application directory structure. This is because `each iOS app operates within its own sandbox`.

See Apple's docs on this: [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

You can interact with other applications such as the music app using [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html), but I've never tried adding files to this, only playing files.

You could always experiment with iCloud integration? Although this will still appear in your sandbox I think.

Comment: thank you for your response. We can save the image files into camera Roll album using this method UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum. Later we can get it from there(camera Roll). Do you know any method similar for saving audio file in xcode?

Comment: Hey, I've never tried this, nor have I seen anything in the docs about this. Why is it such a problem that the app size get's bigger? Regardless of what happens, the phone will still need storage space for it.